# Relaxing constexpr requirement for enum class and bool template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the code where there is a function `accumulate` that does heavy lifting an a dispatcher function `process`. The accumulate function tests a parameter in a hot loop, so the parameter is templated.

```cpp
enum class Op {
  Multiply,
  Add
};

template<Op op>
int accumulate(const std::vector<int> &vec) {
  int a = op == Op::Multiply ? 1 : 0;
  for (int v : vec)
    if constexpr (op == Op::Add) a += v; else a *= v;
  return a;
}

int process(const std::vector<int> &vec, Op op) {
  return accumulate<op>(vec);
}
```

You may have noticed that this code won't compile as the template parameter passed from process is not a constexpr. However, when the template parameter is a bool or, especially, an enum class there is no reason why this shouldn't be compiled.

Such code arises a lot in practice, when a function doing the heavy lifting has several variants (and we only want to keep a single copy in the code base). Is there a proposal or discussion to make such code valid in the future?

(C++ has way too many features, though this one particular one that I need is missing :p )

Comment: `However, when the template parameter is a bool or, especially, an enum class there is no reason why this shouldn't be compiled.` There is, `op` is no compile time constant. The type doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @tkausl When it's an enum class or a bool, the compiler 1) knows all the possibilities. 2) There are only few of them. This is enough to be able to compile the code

Comment: There is a proposal for [JIT](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1609r0.html)

Comment: @tkausl That's the whole point of the question: that when the template parameter is enum class or bool you can actually compile it

Comment: The problem with allowing an enum is you can make enum values that don't exist in the enumeration.

Comment: @NathanOliver Not with `enum class`

Comment: Even for an enum class.  Look at `std::byte`.  You can do `std::byte foo{42}` even though `std::byte` has no enumerations.

Comment: @boinkboink: Even with `enum class`, you might be limited with underlying type though, but then enum would not be a special case.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, I was not able to understand how `std::byte` is relevant to the topic here. Would be very happy to hear more

Comment: @boinkboink: [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) is an example of enum class which may have value outside of predefined enum value (as it has none, it is simply `enum class byte : unsigned char {}`).

Answer (score 0):

> However, when the template parameter is a bool or, especially, an enum class there is no reason why this shouldn't be compiled.

When the parameter is a `bool` or an `enum` with few values, nothing forbid you to choose the case with an `if` or a `switch`

```
int process1 (const std::vector<int> &vec, bool b) {
  if ( b == true )
     return accumulate<true>(vec);
  else
     return accumulate<false>(vec);
}


int process2 (const std::vector<int> &vec, Op op) {
  switch ( op ) {
     case Op::Multiply:
        return accumulate<Op::Multiply>(vec);
        break;

     case Op::Add:
        return accumulate<Op::Add>(vec);
        break;

     // other cases

     // default
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's how the code base currently looks like. I think this a pretty common occurrence especially in the context of api services: there are various parameters in the incoming requests and for speed we template the implementation. It would be so nice if this switch dispatching could be offloaded to the compiler. Switch blocks are tedious and source of many trivial bugs. Add one more type of request, add a new entry into the switch block but oh you forgot the break statement, glhf

Comment: @boinkboink - with the current language, the only alternative I know is embed the `op` value in a `std::integral_constant`; so the value can be passed as argument of the function and the different `op` value become a different type.

Comment: @boinkboink: There are possible warnings for missing break, missing case for switch.

Comment: But even with `std::integral_constant`, conversion/dispatch from runtime value to compile time value should be done.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Oh, yes: I was thinking the use of `std::integral_constant` in case the `op` value is compile-time known (template parameter or `constexpr` value) to the caller of `process()`.